# Program that takes encoded directed graphs and draws them graphically?

Tags: encoding, graph, computer-science, directed-graph

So I have some encoded directed graphs in the form:

```
(1,2,3,4),((1,2),(2,1),(3,4))
```

So just basic list of nodes and then a list of edges. Is there a program that will let me pipe in a string like that and draw it, so I don't have to draw the graph manually by hand ?

Comment: [DOT / Graphviz is made for this.](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grapviz.

try:

```
digraph G {
    A->B
    A->C
    A->D
    D->B
}
```

for example.

Comment: With a little find and replace in a text editor I got my encoding to be properly formatted without too much hassle. Using GVEdit in the bin folder which was included in my download because the pure command line stuff is confusing.

Comment: No idea what that means, all the graphs I give to dot are outputs from programs, @user1086516 - Unix Philosophy, write programs to work together :)